# Django forloop index operations

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates

I'm having a difficult time understanding what Django's forloop.counter is.  My intention is to wrap each three iterations of a for loop in a `<div>`. How I would expect it to work is something like:

```
{% for staff in staff_members %}
    {% if (forloop.counter + 2 % 3) == 0 %} // if loop is the first of three
    <div class="row">
    {% endif %}
        {{ staff }}

    // close <div class="row"> if loop is last of three
{% endfor %}
```

This doesn't work because it seems Django doesn't like to operate on the forloop.counter.  It seems overly complicated to do this operation in the view, I'd much rather do it in the template as it's purely a presentational / style issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cycle` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle).

For example:

```
from django.template import Template, Context
t = Template("""
{% for staff in staff_members %}
     {% cycle '<div class="row">' '' '' as div %}
     {{ staff }}
     {% cycle '' '' '</div>' as div %}
{% endfor %}
{% if not staff_members|length|divisibleby:3 %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
""")
print t.render(Context({'staff_members': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}))
```

prints (some empty lines removed to make it easy to read)

```
<div class="row">
1
2
3
</div>

<div class="row">
4
5
6
</div>

<div class="row">
7
8
</div>
```

**UPDATE** Handle closing tag.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with "Django not liking to operate on the counter". It's simply that Django's template language does not support those sorts of operations, on *any* variables, by design.

As others have noted, there are tags that can do what you Want. The easiest way is probably with `divisibleby`:

```
{% for staff in staff_members %}
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
    <div class="row">
    {% endif %}
    {{ staff }}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I see. I'm much more familiar with the Twig templating language which sometimes blurs the line between view and template sometimes. Appreciate your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use '[divisibleby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby)' along with [cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) (as stated by @falsetru) builtins,

For your specific requirement, following will do,

```
>>> t3 = Template("""
... {% for staff in staff_members %}
...    {% cycle '<div class="row">' '' '' %}
...    {{staff}}
...    {%if forloop.counter|divisibleby:'3' %}
...    </div>
...   {%endif%}
... {%endfor%}
... """)
>>> print t3.render(Context({'staff_members': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}))


   <div class="row">
   1

   2

   3

   </div>


   <div class="row">
   4

   5

   6

   </div>


   <div class="row">
   7

   8

   9

   </div>


   <div class="row">
   10
```

You will need to add extra <\div> in the end if len(staff_members)%3 != 0. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

forloop.counter gives current iteration of loop and is 1-indexed (that is for first iteration value of forloop.counter is 1)